# Can't CollectionViewCell Dynamic Label Width in TableViewCell

Tags: uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I placed a **CollectionView** inside a **TableViewCell**. I added a **Label** inside the **CollectionViewCell** and set up all the constraints using **Xib**. However, the **CollectionView** still relies on the width and height values in the **Show Size Inspector** section. I have set the **Estimate Size** value to **Automatic** in the **Show Size Inspector** tab, but the **CollectionViewCell** continues to be dependent on the **Width** and **Height** values within the **Show Size Inspector**. When I correctly set all the constraints, it should be dynamic. What am I doing wrong?

**Simulator SS:**

[image]

**MainVC:**

```
final class MainVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerCells()
    }
    
    private func registerCells() {
        tableView.register(cellClass: CategoryListCell.self)
    }
}

extension MainVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeue(CategoryListCell.self, indexPath: indexPath) {
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

**CategoryListCell(XIB):**

[image]

**CategoryListCell:**

```
class CategoryListCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let categories: [String] = [
        "All",
        "Nature",
        "Horror",
        "Crovd",
        "Apartments",
        "Planets"
    ]
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        registerCell()
        let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionFlowLayout
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    private func registerCell() {
        collectionView.register(cellClass: CategoryListItemCell.self)
    }
}

extension CategoryListCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeue(CategoryListItemCell.self, indexPath: indexPath) {
            cell.prepareCell(with: categories[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

**CategoryListItemCell(XIB):**

[image]

**CategoryListItemCell:**

```
final class CategoryListItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet private var categoryTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var bottomLineView: UIView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        bottomLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bottomLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryTitleLabel.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func prepareCell(with model: String) {
        categoryTitleLabel.text = model
    }
}
```

Comment: Without actually trying to build your XIBs, from your screen-caps it **looks like** you are setting a Width constraint on `Bottom Line View` to `4.0` ... in your `CategoryListItemCell` class, delete the `awakeFromNib()` code; in your XIB, delete the `Width: 4.0` constraint; also in your XIB, constrain `Bottom Line View` width equal to `Category Title Label` width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your XIBs, and the issue is that you have your `Bottom Line View` constrained to `width = 4`.

Then, in your class `awakeFromNib()` you are setting the **`categoryTitleLabel`** width equal to the **`bottomLineView`** width -- so the label width is then ***also*** `4`.

Change the constraints in your XIB to this (I set the label background to yellow so we can see it):

[image]

Note: I also set the label's Vertical Content Hugging Priority to Required (1000).

and your class becomes:

```
final class CategoryListItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet private var categoryTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var bottomLineView: UIView!

    func prepareCell(with model: String) {
        categoryTitleLabel.text = model
    }
}
```

The result -- view background is light-gray, table is white, collection view background is green:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. I saw my problem. I understood now.